# Insert href in CSS. Possible?

Tags: css, hyperlink, href

I have small images coming from a big one in css. I would like them to have a different link each one and I was wonderin if is there any option to insert on it. thanks

```
.PP-3000469 .BL {
background-position:-375px -192px
}
```

This is my html content:

```
<span class="provider"><div class="PP-3000271"><span class="BL"></span></div></span>
```

how can I get that the content in the this class, when I click takes me to www.google.com for example

Comment: It might be easier to use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: How could I do it with jquery. There are various hundred classes. how can add the href with javascript? Thanks

Comment: are you saying you want it to do something like this: if the class is google.com, make the link go to google.com? you are being very unclear

Comment: This div are generated dinamically. it charges a img inside BL, and I would like each one to have a different link. If there are any chance to insert in the css will be the easiest way for me to do it.

Comment: so, for example, you might want elements with a class `PP-3000469` to go to google.com, ones with `PP-7584392` to go to microsoft.com, ones with `PP-4689304` to go to apple.com, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull this off with jQuery. Assuming you have the file included in the HTML file,

```
$(".PP-3000469 .BL").attr("href", "url");
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need to check the the href. I need to include it depending on the class CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like OK but it is not working for me :( 
This is the html content:  <span class="provider"><div class="PP-3000271"><span class="BL"></span></div></span>

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with css. But here's a way to do it with JavaScript (no jQuery needed):

```
var classElts=document.getElementsByClassName('PP-3000469');
for(var i=classElts.length;i>0;i--){
    classElts[i].setAttribute('href','http://example.com/');
}
```

Comment: I suggested jQuery because it's a little easier to understand and write.

Comment: I suggest not using jQuery because it is really stupid to use a really big library so you can make some links on your website

Comment: Right you are. He can use what he wants, I suppose

Comment: @JordanFitz i win this time

Comment: @Markasoftware looks like it :)

Answer (score -3):

Like @markasoftware i suggest using javascript

```
var classElts=document.getElementsByClassName('PP-3000469');
for(var i=classElts.length;i>0;i--){
classElts[i].setAttribute('href','http://example.com/');
}
```

There is no way to use just css, because css is just styling.

Comment: First off, you copied my code character for character. Even the variable names are the same. Seconds, css actually can be used for hover effects/animations, not JUST styling. Also, with the transform, animation, and transitions that have come to CSS lately it is somewhat more than JUST styling these days. But the -1 I'm about to give you is because you copied my code.